# VS Code Vim - command to copy between registers

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

In VS Code Vim extension I would like to add a keyboard binding to copy between registers. I Vim one does that via mapping `:let @a=@b`. But `let` is not supported in the extension. So is there is way to do that?

What I originally wanted is to make Ctrl-C in the normal mode to copy a register to the system keyboard using the default register if none is given. But I could not figure out a command to get that.